# ASP.NET Core - Fetch API doesn't post data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, http-post, fetch-api, dbcontext

I've been trying to create a ASP.NET core web app to send the data input on page to my server.I have one table that contains one row with dropdowns for the first three columns and a checkbox for the fourth column. I'm using fetch API with HTTPPost, however there's error saying that the api/saveData was not found (404).

Here's my code:

CSHTML

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Checkbox</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" id="column1Select">
                    <option>Option 1</option>
                    <option>Option 2</option>
                    <option>Option 3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" id="column2Select">
                    <option>Option A</option>
                    <option>Option B</option>
                    <option>Option C</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" id="column3Select">
                    <option>Choice X</option>
                    <option>Choice Y</option>
                    <option>Choice Z</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxInput" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- You can add more rows here if needed -->
    </tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="postData()">Submit</button>


function postData() {
    var column1Value = document.getElementById("column1Select").value;
    var column2Value = document.getElementById("column2Select").value;
    var column3Value = document.getElementById("column3Select").value;
    var isChecked = document.getElementById("checkboxInput").checked;
    
    var data = {
        column1: column1Value,
        column2: column2Value,
        column3: column3Value,
        isChecked: isChecked
    };

    fetch('api/saveData', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
        .then(response =\> response.json())
        .then(responseData =\> {
            console.log('Success:', responseData);
        })
        .catch(error =\> {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
}
```

CS

```
public class splitModel : PageModel {    
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DataController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public DataController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("SaveData")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SaveData([FromBody] StockTable data)
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid data received");
            }

            Console.Write(data.Column1);

            var newStockTable = new ApplicationDbContext.StockTable
            {
                Column1 = data.Column1,
                Column2 = data.Column2,
                Column3 = data.Column3, 
                IsChecked = data.IsChecked,
            };

            try
            {
                _context.StockTables.Add(newStockTable);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Ok("Data saved successfully");
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException ex)
            {
                // Log the exception details for troubleshooting
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return BadRequest("Error saving data: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        public class StockTable
        {
            public int Id { get; set; } // Assuming this is your primary key column (integer type)
            public string Column1 { get; set; } // Example: string column in your database
            public string Column2 { get; set; } // Another string column
            public string Column3 { get; set; } // Another string column
            public bool IsChecked { get; set; } // Assuming this is a boolean column in your database
        }

        public class StockDataModel
        {
            public string Column1 { get; set; }
            public string Column2 { get; set; }
            public string Column3 { get; set; }
            public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        }

    }`
```

I've tried to fetch my data to 'https://reqres.in/api/users/23', it works with responses like

```
Success: {    
"column1": "Option 1",     
"column2": "Option B",     
"column3": "Choice X",     
"isChecked": true,     
"id": "17",     
"createdAt": "2023-10-22T09:30:31.259Z"}
```

Comment: Probably the API route should be: `api/Data/SaveData`. Or check the request sent is to the correct domain and URL path. One thing you need to confirm is that the controller is really placed in the `SplitModel` class? If yes, I would suggest to move the `DataController` as the root class. It shouldn't be place in the PageModel and I don't see the PageModel is needed here.

Answer (score 1):

As Yong Shun said, you can use ApiController  class  as the root class.

DataController class:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DataController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public DataController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("SaveData")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveData([FromBody] StockTable data)
    {...}
}
```

Try to modify your uri like: `api/Data/SaveData` , when you add route `[Route("api/[controller]")]`.

If you remove the`[Route("api/[controller]")]`, and just use   `[Route("SaveData")]` on SaveData action , you can use uri like: `SaveData`.

Besides, make sure you have the controllers route for your Api controllers in Progarm.cs, like:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
app.MapControllers();
```

And, add `'Accept': 'application/json',` in your headers, like:

```
fetch('api/Data/saveData', {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },
     body: JSON.stringify(data)
 })
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(responseData => {
         console.log('Success:', responseData);
     })
     .catch(error => {
         console.error('Error:', error);
     });
```

headers—specifies the Accept and Content-Type HTTP request headers. Both headers are set to application/json to specify the media type being received and sent, respectively.

result:
[image]

You can have a look at [Tutorial: Call an ASP.NET Core web API with JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-javascript?view=aspnetcore-6.0)  and [Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) to know more.

Comment: Hi @Katie Lou , any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue? 
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know?

Comment: Sorry for the infrequent activity here; the code worked successfully! And I found out that I might have duplicated the data controllers, another one in my controller .cs class. Many thanks for your help. @QingGuo